# How can we extract headings from PDF document in C#

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, classification, data-extraction

I am able to extract text from the PDF document using **iTextsharp** but I am not able to classify the extracted text into headings and its paragraph content. I just need **headings** of the paragraph from the document. Since it is a unstructured document we are not able to use the font properties like **Bold, Font Size**. Please help me on this.

Comment: Sounds like magic

Comment: *"Since it is a unstructured document we are not able to use the font properties like Bold, Font Size"* - well... what *can* you use? As only you have the documents, how can we tell?